# Save stack traces while syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, fast-sync, transaction-trace

I have been working on a project, where I would like to trace all transactions from a block and for this reason I have been using a fast-syncing node. It works well, the only issue is that querying the node using the *debug_traceBlockByHash* endpoint is very slow. Slower than the speed of new blocks being mined. For this reason after a few blocks, I get behind and eventually due to pruning of the data, I don't have access to trace information anymore. So, my question is if it's possible to save the trace information during syncing or when receiving a new block. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run multiple nodes doing `debug_traceBlockByHash`
2. Split the work across multiple nodes e.g. by a block number
3. Reconcialiate the results at the end to a database

I believe this is how EtherScan operates its nodes.

Comment: Thank you very much, very helpful answer :)

Comment: No problem Jani.